# How to enable incognito mode in chrome when using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have added  `options.addArguments("--incognito");` to use chrome incognito. However I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 

Build info: version: '4.5.0', revision: 'fe167b119a'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.2.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-application-cache, --incognito, --no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --disable-application-cache], extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:\AutomationFramework\mvn-..., profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0}}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-application-cache, --incognito, --no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --disable-application-cache], extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:\AutomationFramework\mvn-..., profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0}}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:70)
    at com.company.IniWebDriver.OpenBrowser(IniWebDriver.java:139)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:306)
```

code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
```

The chrome version is 106.0.5249.119 and the chrome driver version is 106.0.5249.61.

Is there any other way to use incognito without using ChromeOptions? After chromedriver update, chrome incognito stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add options to capabilities?

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver chromedriver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: yes I have added but still same error

Comment: Do you have a selenium docker container or standalone?

Comment: it's standalone